# I need an advice about learning directed angles

Tags: geometry, book-recommendation

Today I learned a bit about directed angles and to be honest it's not clear for me at all. Can someone suggest me any resources like books or videos to learn this thing deeply? Also I tried to search it on the web but only results I get are coterminal angles in trigonometry and I don't want this because in my book author (Evan Chen's Olympiad geometry) doesn't use directed angles as trigonometry subject.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Thank you very much. I edited the post.

Comment: Just think of a directed angle as a rotation. A rotation can either be counterclockwise (usually taken as $+$) or clockwise (taken as $-$) about a fixed point. Also, the rotation can be as much as you want. So we have an amount of rotation for every real number.

Comment: Yes I know it already but I don't know how and where use it and I wanted exercises for complete beginners or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Try to correlate directed angles in $\mathbb R^3$ to angle of inclination in $\mathbb R^2$. In $\mathbb R^2$ concept of directed angles is trivial because period of $\color{brown}{\tan x}$ is π .

Comment: I tried it and I think I understand little bit more so thank you very much! Anyways is there any good source for learning this stuff?

Comment: Almost every book which derives equation of a line in R³ shall be helpful.